# Converting MS publisher HTML document to PDF in MPDF php

Tags: php, mpdf

My client shared with us an MS publisher document and I need to convert it to PDF and I am using MPDF php library. I can convert it to PDF but it is not populating correctly. How can I fix this? We have multiple HTML file every page contains CSS with HTML.

I am sharing complete HTML file :

https://send.firefox.com/download/779adca107/#fpyvJs44byBMUggBYnu8bg

Comment: Please share your error code so we can better give you some suggestions.THanks

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the rest of the code.

Comment: I have sent a url where you can download complete HTML